# how to draw lines from a plugin or via messages

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

can anyone tell me how to draw lines via messages or from a plugin?
I already tried DynamicLines and Scene->DrawLine from inside a world plugin
but without results. It either crashed the server or nothing happened at all.

Thanks for the help and best regards
Bastian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/54/how-to-draw-lines-from-a-plugin-or-via-messages/) by [Karandaras](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/46/karandaras/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 76 on 2012-10-11

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Thanks for the answer.
I already added a simple way of drawing to the Scene class. It is probably not the best way, but it works for me and allows me to continue my work.

Here is the code I used for that.

Added needed stuff to the Scene header

### gazebo/rendering/Scene.hh

```
/// \brief Subscribe to draw for line drawing
private: transport::SubscriberPtr drawingSub;

/// \brief Drawing callback
/// \param[in] _msg The message data.
private: void OnDrawing(ConstDrawingPtr &_msg);

/// \brief Process a drawing message
/// \param[in] _msg The message data.
private: bool ProcessDrawingMsg(ConstDrawingPtr &_msg);

/// \def DrawingMsgs_L
/// \brief List of drawing messages.
typedef std::list<boost::shared_ptr<msgs::Drawing const> > DrawingMsgs_L;

/// \brief List of drawing message to process.
private: DrawingMsgs_L drawingMsgs;
```

New functions for the drawing

### gazebo/rendering/Scene.cc

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
void Scene::OnDrawing(ConstDrawingPtr &_msg)
{
  boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(*this->receiveMutex);
  this->drawingMsgs.push_back(_msg);
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
bool Scene::ProcessDrawingMsg(ConstDrawingPtr &_msg)
{
  Ogre::SceneNode *sceneNode = NULL;
  Ogre::ManualObject *obj = NULL;
  bool attached = false;

  if (this->manager->hasManualObject(_msg->name()))
  {
    sceneNode = this->manager->getSceneNode(_msg->name());
    obj = this->manager->getManualObject(_msg->name());
    attached = true;
  }
  else
  {
    sceneNode = this->manager->getRootSceneNode()->createChildSceneNode(_msg->name());
    obj = this->manager->createManualObject(_msg->name());
  }

  sceneNode->setVisible(_msg->visible());
  obj->setVisible(_msg->has_visible());
  obj->estimateVertexCount(_msg->point_size());

  obj->clear();
  std::string material = "Gazebo/Red";
  if(_msg->has_material()) {
    material = _msg->material();
  }

  if(!_msg->has_mode())
    obj->begin(material, Ogre::RenderOperation::OT_LINE_LIST);
  else if(_msg->mode() == msgs::Drawing::POINT_LIST)
    obj->begin(material, Ogre::RenderOperation::OT_POINT_LIST);
  else if(_msg->mode() == msgs::Drawing::LINE_LIST)
    obj->begin(material, Ogre::RenderOperation::OT_LINE_LIST);
  else if(_msg->mode() == msgs::Drawing::LINE_STRIP)
    obj->begin(material, Ogre::RenderOperation::OT_LINE_STRIP);
  else if(_msg->mode() == msgs::Drawing::TRIANGLE_LIST)
    obj->begin(material, Ogre::RenderOperation::OT_TRIANGLE_LIST);
  else if(_msg->mode() == msgs::Drawing::TRIANGLE_STRIP)
    obj->begin(material, Ogre::RenderOperation::OT_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
  else if(_msg->mode() == msgs::Drawing::TRIANGLE_FAN)
    obj->begin(material, Ogre::RenderOperation::OT_TRIANGLE_FAN);

  int p = _msg->point_size();
  for(int i=0; i<p; i++) {
    obj->position(_msg->point(i).position().x(), _msg->point(i).position().y(), _msg->point(i).position().z());
    if(_msg->point(i).has_color())
      obj->colour(Conversions::Convert(msgs::Convert(_msg->point(i).color())));
  }
  obj->end();

  if (!attached)
    sceneNode->attachObject(obj);

  if(_msg->has_pose()) {
    sceneNode->setPosition(Conversions::Convert(msgs::Convert(_msg->pose().position())));
    sceneNode->setOrientation(Conversions::Convert(msgs::Convert(_msg->pose().orientation())));
  }

  return true;
}
```

Changes adding the new function to be processed during prerender

### gazebo/rendering/Scene.cc

```
void Scene::PreRender()
{
  // ...
  static SensorMsgs_L::iterator sensorIter;
  static LinkMsgs_L::iterator linkIter;
  static DrawingMsgs_L::iterator drawingIter;

  // ...
  // Process the link messages
  linkIter = this->linkMsgs.begin();
  while (linkIter != this->linkMsgs.end())
  {
    if (this->ProcessLinkMsg(*linkIter))
      this->linkMsgs.erase(linkIter++);
    else
      ++linkIter;
  }

  // Process the drawing messages
  drawingIter = this->drawingMsgs.begin();
  while (drawingIter != this->drawingMsgs.end())
  {
    if (this->ProcessDrawingMsg(*drawingIter))
      this->drawingMsgs.erase(drawingIter++);
    else
      ++drawingIter;
  }
  // ...
}
```

Registering the new subscriber

### gazebo/rendering/Scene.cc

```
Scene::Scene(const std::string &_name, bool _enableVisualizations)
{
  // ...
  this->sceneSub = this->node->Subscribe("~/scene", &Scene::OnScene, this);

  this->drawingSub = this->node->Subscribe("~/draw", &Scene::OnDrawing, this);
  // ...
}
```

Message definition

### gazebo/msgs/drawing.proto

```
package gazebo.msgs;

/// \ingroup gazebo_msgs
/// \interface Drawing 
/// \brief Message that is used to draw inside gazebo
/// \verbatim

import "vector3d.proto";
import "pose.proto";
import "color.proto";

message Drawing
{
  enum Mode
  {
    POINT_LIST     = 1;
    LINE_LIST      = 2;
    LINE_STRIP     = 3;
    TRIANGLE_LIST  = 4;
    TRIANGLE_STRIP = 5;
    TRIANGLE_FAN   = 6;
  }
  
  message Point
  {
    required Vector3d position  = 1;
    optional Color color        = 2;
  }


  required string name          = 1;
  required bool visible         = 2;
  optional Pose pose            = 3;
  optional string material      = 4;
  optional Mode mode            = 5;
  repeated Point point          = 6;
}

/// \endverbatim
```

It is probably not the best way to solve my problem, but it works for me.

Bastian

Here are the files/patches, hope everything works, since I am not familiar with diff

[Drawing.proto](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/d4iyi2qbqtj3phu/drawing.proto?dl=1)

Patch for [CMakeLists.txt](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/cgm8s9jxsqinkw5/CMakeLists.patch?dl=1)

Patch for [Scene.cc](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/t49u4bg77p1n9i7/Scene.cc.patch?dl=1)

Patch for [Scene.hh](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/mgahnodqfzz88yt/Scene.hh.patch?dl=1)

---

Originally posted by [Karandaras](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/46/karandaras/) with karma: 76 on 2012-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Karandaras](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/46/karandaras/) on 2013-01-05**:
I would be glad to hear if my code got used. Keep up the good work with the simulator.

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-01-09**:
I will start integrating you code shortly. For future reference, it's better to submit changes through a pull request on our bitbucket site: http://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo.

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-01-11**:
Ticketed here: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/382/render-via-message